# Tampermonkey script to change one line of code

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I would like to change this :

```
<a class="disabled">Import</a>
```

Into this :

```
<a href="javascript:importCsv();">Import</a>
```

So I make this code, I'am new to tampermonkey and JS :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         CSV Import
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Make CSV great again
// @author       You
// @match        https://
// @icon         https://
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    const change = document.getElementsByTagName('a').getElementsByClassName("disabled");
    change.className = "";
    const change2 = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    change2.href = "javascript:importCsv();";
})();
```

It does not work !

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with Tampermonkey but I'm assuming it will just run your script on a page. For that you are doing at least two things wrong.

First; `document.getElementsByTagName('a')` returns a `HTMLCollection`, you can't call `getElementsByClassName()` on such a list. A better approach would be to use `document.querySelector('a.disabled')` to get the first anchor element with the class "disabled".

Second; You are getting a second `HTMLCollection` that you set the `href` property on which also won't work. You need a single element for it to take effect, and you need the right one.

Something like this might do it (unless there are several disabled anchors, then you need a more precise selector).

```js
(function() {
    const disabledAnchor = document.querySelector('a.disabled')
    disabledAnchor.className = '';
    disabledAnchor.href = 'javascript:importCsv();';
})();
```

I would also consider using a proper event callback instead of setting `href`. This is easily done using `addEventListener()`.

```js
(function() {
    const disabledAnchor = document.querySelector('a.disabled')
    disabledAnchor.className = '';
    disabledAnchor.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        window.importCsv();
    });
})();
```